# Is there any issue in executing Installvalidate Custom Action after InstallInitialize in InstallShield basic MSI?

Tags: windows-installer

My MSI installer is showing reboot required dialog box during un-install since my custom action to stop service is scheduled after InstallValidate. The service stop CA is a deferred action to elevate privileges so it is scheduled after InstallInitialize. I need to  schedule the InstallValidate CA after my service stop CA to prevent showing the reboot required dialog box. Is there any problem in placing InstallValidate CA after InstallInitialize?

Answer (score 2):

It won't work.

InstallValidate is an immediate action. So it will always run before InstallInitialize which is deferred.

The correct approach is to make your service stop itself. For this you can use a global event or a trigger handled by your service. This way you don't need Administrator privileges.